# Secure front fork when mounting on roof rack

Tags: car-rack

I would like a way to secure my front fork/handlebars so they are always pointing directly forward when I load my bike on my roof rack.

It makes it hard to get the fork on the fork mount when the fork is turning as I struggle to get it up there.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: This would seem to depend a lot on what rack your bike is mounted on and the roof rack of your car. But you could use some velco straps maybe?

Comment: On occasion (when I had a roof rack) I would use a bungee to hold the front fork in a fixed position relative to the bike while installing on the rack.  I don't recall any particulars, though.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are talking about the process of loading the bike, not when the bike is up there and the car is in movement (since most bike racks have a kind of trough that keeps the front wheel aligned).

What I have done on occasion is to loosen the handlebar and turn it backwards about 75 degrees relative to the fork. The handlebar is then more or less aligned with the front wheel. Re-tighten the handlebar in this position. Then a bungee or other elastic material can be used to fix the handlebar to the horizontal frame bar.

This does mean using an Allen key in most cases, but I figure it is worth getting the key out.